# Improve Percentage Stats on Profile

Tags: feature-request, reputation, profile-page, reputation-leagues

Currently, when I look at the reputation section of my profile I see something of the format `top X% <time period>`. Okay, cool. However, recently I've been topping the charts at [Christianity.SE](http://christianity.stackexchange.com), but the percentage values seem odd.

For example, yesterday (UTC yesterday) I had around ~400 rep this week. According to the Users page, I was the top user for the week. But my profile just said "Top 4% this week"

Now, today, I'm at around ~500 rep this week, and it says "Top 2% this week."  Huh?

[image]

First of all, if i'm *the* top user, why not just say "Top user this week" - that would not only be more descriptive, it's a nice pleasant reward for a user checking his rep stats.

Second, what's with the arbitrary percentage values? If I'm the top user, I'm in the top 1%, so why not say so? Why 4% or 2%? How is this calculated, and why?

**tl;dr**, can't the `top X% <time period>` be "prettier"?

Comment: Reputation is fluid and most pages you see are cached (i.e. not live data). It wouldn't make much sense to show actual live figures for something so horribly unimportant, top 2% is a good enough approximation.

Comment: @YannisRizos true, but the Users page is live. As soon as my rep changes it's reflected in the Users page.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I'm a data nerd and I love precision (+1), it's the competitive element in this that I don't really like (-1). So, no vote. ;P

Comment: @YannisRizos well, I wouldn't mind if it would at least say Top 1%. That makes sense. The "top 4%" seems like a bug, to me. But yeah, I guess the "top user!" could be quite competitive.

Answer (score 2):

The [leagues](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/139/week/christianity) only track users with 200 rep or more. [Christianity](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/) is still a smallish site, so, for example, if only 25 users (with 200 rep or more) earned rep between April 1 and April 5, then even if you were the #1 user that week, you'd still only be in the top 4% of the week on April 5.

Comment: For a clarification, the `top [pct] % this [time-period] ` stats use as a denominator just users with 200+ rep, or just users with 200+ rep who have accumulated points this [time-period]?